# How do you use Thrift protocol via corporate Proxy?

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, thrift-protocol, zipkin

I've had a search over the internet but can't seem to find any straightforward instructions on how to use the Thrift protocol from behind a proxy.

To give you a bit of background - we have a Zipkin instance setup (https://github.com/twitter/zipkin) that uses a Cassandra instance (http://cassandra.apache.org/) to store Zipkin traces. Our intention is to negotiate over the thrift protocol to a collector that is then responsible for writing traces to Cassandra.

What conditions have to be in place for us to negotiate successfully via our corporate proxy? Do we just have to set certain proxy properties when trying to negotiate or do we have to set something else up that allows this negotiation to happen?

Any help people can give in this direction with regards to resources and/or an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache Thrift TSocketTransport (almost certainly what you are using) uses TCP on a configurable port. Cassandra usually uses port 9160 for thrift. When using Thrift/TCP no HTTP setup is necessary. Just open 9160 (and any other ports your custom thrift servers may be listening on).

Though you can use Thrift over HTTP, Thrift is RPC, not REST, so proxy caching will cause problems, the client needs a direct comm channel with the server.

Comment: Thank you. I'll investigate a bit further. If anything comes of it I'll note it here

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to access a thrift service via a proxy, something like this would work:

https://github.com/totally/thrift_goodies/blob/master/transport.py

You can kill the kerberos stuff if you don't need that.